# Transpose datatable id / header / value to another table with those headers

Tags: c#, linq

I have data currently parsed in to a .Net `System.Data.DataTable` in this format:

```
ID | Header | Value

 1    Name    Jim
 1    Age     34
 1   Gender    M

 2    Name   Gibby
 2    Age     32
 2   Gender    F

 3    Name    Bob
 3    Age     100
 3   Gender    U
```

and I need to get it into another DataTable that has those fields:

```
ID | Name | Age | Gender
1    Jim    34      M
2    Gill   32      F
3    Bob    100     U
```

This is achievable in SQL using:

```
select id,
       max(case when header = 'Name' then Value end) as name,
       max(case when header = 'Age' then Value end) as Age,
       max(case when header = 'Gender' then Value end) as Gender
from pivottest
group by id;
```

but this means I'd need to update a sql table with the values and then run this query, where I'd prefer to do it in a c# method before pushing it to the DB.

Is this possible to do in C#, probably using Linq? Where would I even start?!

Comment: Does it need to be another DataTable? Could it be in a list of 'Person' objects, where Person is a new class and has properties Id, Name, Age, Gender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't mind that it's not returned in a DataTable, you could actually create a list of persons like this:

Group the data in the data table by Id:

```
var groups = <yourDataTable>.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Id"));
```

Create a class called Person and Enum for Gender:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    M,
    F,
    U
}
```

Create a list of persons called "people" and loop through the groupings and map them to a Person like this:

```
var people = new List<Person>();

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    people.Add(new Person
    {
        Id = group.Key,
        Name = group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>("Header") == "Name").Field<string>("Value"),
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>("Header") == "Age").Field<string>("Value")),
        Gender = (Gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>("Header") == "Gender").Field<string>("Value"))
    });
}
```

I put this into a console app to demonstrate:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new DataTable();
        data.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        data.Columns.Add("Header", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

        data.Rows.Add(1, "Name", "Jim");
        data.Rows.Add(1, "Age", "34");
        data.Rows.Add(1, "Gender", "M");
        data.Rows.Add(2, "Name", "Gibby");
        data.Rows.Add(2, "Age", "32");
        data.Rows.Add(2, "Gender", "F");
        data.Rows.Add(3, "Name", "Bob");
        data.Rows.Add(3, "Age", "100");
        data.Rows.Add(3, "Gender", "U");

        Console.WriteLine("Current data:");

        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("id: {0}, header: {1}, value: {2}", row[0], row[1], row[2]);
        }

        var groups = data.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Id"));
        var people = new List<Person>();

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            people.Add(new Person
            {
                Id = group.Key,
                Name = group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>("Header") == "Name").Field<string>("Value"),
                Age = Convert.ToInt32(group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>("Header") == "Age").Field<string>("Value")),
                Gender = (Gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>("Header") == "Gender").Field<string>("Value"))
            });
        }

        Console.WriteLine("People list data:");

        foreach (var person in people)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, Name: {1}, Age: {2}, Gender: {3}", person.Id, person.Name, person.Age, person.Gender.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    M,
    F,
    U
}
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: This is great. I'd thought about creating proper model classes for the data and because I can use this method to map the data across, I'll be able to do it. It'll take a bit of setup but will save me (and everyone who uses it) a lot of time in the future. Thanks!